# Handle byte[] with ByteBuffer

Tags: java, string, arrays, nio, bytebuffer

I try to access a byte[] via a ByteBuffer in order to represent a file-type I defined. The first positions within the byte[] contain some Metadata and get treated with bit-manipulations. So they do not represent a char at all.

I want to add file-data (chars e. g.) at a certain fixed position.

`byte[] file_portion` contains a portion of a large file: the beginning section. Which includes the header with the Metadata.
`content` is a String with information I want to add to that buffer. start_pos is the first position to hold the new file-data from content.

```
ByteBuffer my_content = ByteBuffer.allocate(this.file_portion.length);
content_buffer.wrap(this.file_portion);

for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
    char tmp = content.toCharArray()[i];
    my_content.put(this.start_pos + i, (byte) tmp)
}
```

If I remap this I get a garbage and emptyness:

```
CharBuffer debug = my_content.asCharBuffer();
System.out.println("debug " + debug);
```

I could understand if the first positions show corrupted chars... but not a single one position is correct.

Comment: Besides the bug, `content.toCharArray()[i]` is ugly, you are allocating a new char array in each loop iteration. Build the char array outside, or use `content.charAt(i)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are adding chars to a ByteBuffer and expecting them to be readable with a CharBuffer view, you should be using putChar(...) not put(...).

**EDITED**: per OP comments.

For example:

```
char[] chars = content.toCharArray();  // removed from loop per leonbloy's excellent comment  
CharBuffer cbuf = my_content.asCharBuffer();

for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
    cbuf.putChar(chars[i]);
}

CharBuffer debug = my_content.asCharBuffer();
System.out.println(debug);

my_content.position(my_content.position() + 2*chars.length);
```

Otherwise the CharBuffer is reading two of your consecutive bytes as a single char.
Now the cbuf buffer will start loading chars at the same point your byte buffer left off.  After loading all of the chars, your original ByteBuffer will be positioned to the next location.  Hopefully this is what you're looking for.

Comment: That .flip() looks very useful. But I still have to add the chars at a specifc position. If I do that with my_content.setPosition(this.start_pos+i) or even + i +1 the whole conversion gets corrupted.

Comment: I guess the point I'm trying to make is that you need to let the Buffers do two things for you to make your life easier.  1) manage the position in the buffer and 2) manage the data format of items being read/written.  In your original code you're trying to do both, and running into problems because of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your efforts. You're absolutly right: managing the position is problematic here and I have to separate this. Still I have the problem that cbuf is filled from position 0. I need to fill it starting from position n. Each time I do this the whole stuff gets corrupted. :(

Comment: @wishi I guess I would need to see more of the context of what you're doing to suggest code that solves your problem.

Comment: Finally got it... thanks for the help. The CharBuffer has the .put(index, char) I needed. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @wishi glad to hear it.  nio Buffers are a great tool.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that in Java a char occupies two bytes?